# Facebook Connect no longer pulling {fbc_facebook_name}

Tags: solspace, facebook, solspace-facebookconnect

Wondering if anyone has seen anything like this lately--might be an issue from Facebook (i.e., affecting all version of Facebook Connect). Or, it might be something particular to these old versions and/or this particular site:

On an EE 1.7.x site running Solspace's Facebook Connect 2.0.9, the `{fbc_facebook_name}` variable suddenly stopped working about 10 days ago. It's used in this code:

```
{exp:fbc:member_data member_id="CURRENT_USER" profile_pic_size="square"}{fbc_facebook_name}{/exp:fbc:member_data}
```

Now, instead of pulling in a user's Facebook name, the unparsed tag shows.

The corresponding symptom is that, when a new user logs in via FBC for the first time, their EE `{name}` is not their Facebook name, but an obvious placeholder name from FBC, like facebook1000000000000.

I can see, as well that other fields like `{fbc_facebook_username}` similarly fail.

But then other aspects of FBC seem to be working fine, and, for example, the site is still pulling the correct FB profile pictures via this:

```
{exp:fbc:member_data member_id="{author_id}" profile_pic_size="square" profile_pic_height="50" profile_pic_width="50"}{fbc_profile_pic}{/exp:fbc:member_data}
```

Anyone see anything like this recently? Any ideas about what's going on?

The only other clue I have is that this issue started right after the Heartbleed bug, and this site did have an SSL certificate change in response to that. But this is maybe (probably?) purely coincidental.